# Loading online database data progress bar

Tags: android, database

I am using Mysql online database in my android application and I am using BackgroundWorker class. I kindly ask how can I create like a loading progress bar or circular loading shape while the data is loading from the online database to the activity or fragment?

Answer (score 1):

create progressDialog in Your Activity or Fragment

and use your network library to get data from server.
To use ProgressDialog use the below code

```
ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
```

To start the ProgressDialog use

```
progressdialog.show();
progressdialog.setCancelable(false); //is used so that ProgressDialog cannot be cancelled until the work is done.
```

To stop the ProgressDialog use this code (when your work is finished):

```
progressdialog.dismiss();`
```

Comment: Actually it haven't worked... It still give me error. Can you give me more details to know where should I exactly put the code? I tried to put the code in BackgroundWorker class but it gives me a fatal error. Any ideas?